# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL (Nvidia, (L)Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: opengl, linker, libraries, ld, ubuntu-12.10

I'm failing to link against OpenGL in my C++/Qt5 projects. I link using the following command:

```
g++ -m64 -Wl,[...] -o [...] [...].o                               \
    -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L[...]/qt-5.0.0/5.0.0/gcc_64/lib          \
    -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Network -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
```

I hope the `[...]` aren't hiding something important. If you think they are, please let me know.

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

I'm on an Lubuntu 12.10 system and using Qt5 from http://qt-project.org/downloads. Since the system is newly installed, the first thing I did was installing Ubuntu's `nvidia-current` package and I rebooted. Among others, the following libraries have been installed on my system:

```
$ ll /usr/lib/nvidia-current/
[...]
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       10 Oct  6 04:58 libGL.so -> libGL.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       15 Oct  6 04:58 libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.304.43
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1076560 Oct  6 04:58 libGL.so.304.43
[...]
```

I googled on how to add this path to the default library search path, as I guessed that `g++` doesn't look in the subfolder `nvidia-current` but only in `/usr/lib`. So I added the path to `ld.conf.d` in Ubuntu. I updated `ldconfig` and checked with the following command:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so
        libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1
        libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1
        libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so
        libGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so
```

So everything looks just fine!
Still (even after rebooting), the error from above appears. Am I missing something?

**Edit:**

After adding `-L/usr/lib/nvidia-current/`, everything works fine. But it seems that this is not the *correct way* to link against a library in a default path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's common for distributions to install graphics drivers' libGL not into the system library path, but some additional directory in `/usr/lib` to allow for installing different variants of `libGL.so` on the same system. Then symlinks to the active `libGL.so` are created by some centralized configuration system, for example `alternatives` as used by Ubuntu and Debian. It may very well be, that this configuration step failed.

`/usr/lib/nvidia-current` is not a standard library path and hence the library is not found; this also should mean, that OpenGL programs should not work. Maybe the Ubuntu folks do something with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to circumvent this.

Personally I suggest that you add symlinks, as you should always have `libGL.so` in the defaul library path, preferrably `/usr/lib` or on 32/64 bit multilib systems in `/usr/lib64` and `/usr/lib32`

```
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib32/libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/libGL.so => /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so
/usr/lib32/libGL.so => /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so
```

You can also do this using the `alternatives` system, adding a new alternative.

Comment: This saved me some time on a x64 system (the names were a bit different, but that didn't matter), thanks!